# ASP.NET layout not showing while running on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, iis

I'm trying to run an ASP.NET application on Windows Server 2008 using IIS 7. The website is the default website that you start with in Visual Studio 2013 with no changes made to it. However, after publishing the website as a deploy package and importing it to my server, the webpage loads, but it looks like this:

[image]

When it's actually supposed to look like this:

[image]

I have tried searching the Internet for solutions but none of them have worked.

Comment: Looks like the stylesheet is either missing or not being applied.  Did you check the server to make sure the CSS file(s) made it there in the publish?

Comment: What is the rendered `<link href=""` to your stylesheet? What happens if you try to request it manually? What does your browser's F12 tools say about what resources were requested?

Comment: The link to the href css is <link href="/TESTSITE/Content/css?v=0CO7wbdAKgh6VVE0St8oKqJBcB4RpFIbcQS63jv2JjY1" rel="stylesheet"/>

Comment: It is probably an issue with the relative paths. It is a bit stupid, but the relative bundle path must match the relative stylesheet path. This is a weird issue which only applies when bundle optimization is on, which is by default only true for published release configurations.